# regex to match coordinates

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex expression in python that can match the following lines - I am just able to match the very first number by doing something like this
[image]
re.compile(r'\d.\d{14}\s+')

but could not do rest. Also tried doing [^-\d] to catch the negative sign - does not seem working.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? The entire line or the individual numbers?

Comment: @Jesse - entire line - thanks!

Comment: individual numbers: ```/-?\d\.\d{14}/``` could works. Entire line works with: ```(-?\d\.\d{14})\s(-?\d\.\d{14})\s(-?\d\.\d{14})\s([oh])``` (regexp101 link)[https://regex101.com/r/o4fdnA/1]

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Answer (score 2):

First, lets start by looking at the numbers. You've already got a decent expression for finding a single number (`\d.\d{14}\s+`), but there are a couple things wrong with it.

1. In regex, `.` indicates any single character. This means that your expression will accept any character after the first digit.
2. It's not taking into account the possibility that there could be a negative sign at the beginning.

Both of these problems are really easy to fix. The first can be fixed by simply escaping the period (`\.`). The second can be fixed by adding the negative sign to the pattern and giving it a quantifier. In this case, the `?` quantifier will be the best option because it matches between 0 and 1 times. All this means is that it won't care if the symbol is there, but if it is it will match it. After these 2 changes, the pattern looks like this: `-?\d\.\d{14}\s+`.

Next, we need to tell it to match more than once. This can be done very easily by putting the pattern in a group and applying a quantifier to said group. Now the question is which quantifier should be used. In your example, there are only 3 numbers before the single character at the end of the line. You can match this pattern exactly 3 times by using the `{3}` quantifier. If you know there will be at least 1 but don't know how many in total there will be, you can use the `+` quantifier. For this example I will be using the `{3}` quantifier just so it's more specific to your question. After adding this, the pattern will look something like this: `(-?\d\.\d{14}\s+){3}`

Now all that's left is to match the character at the end. You can use `\S` to match any single word character. You can add a quantifier to it, but again, for the purposes of your question, I won't be since there's only a single character. The final expression would look like `(-?\d\.\d{14}\s+){3}\S`.